# Skip key index from a range of array's key in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

This is only for arrays with index number. For example i have this arrays;

```
$array = [
  "0" => "number 1",
  "1" => "number 2",
  "2" => "number 3",
  "3" => "number 4",
  "4" => "number 5",
  "5" => "number 6",
  "6" => "number 7",
  "7" => "number 8",
  "8" => "number 9"
];
```

I want to skip the loop from certain range of key indexes for example, skip the foreach if the number of index is from range 0 to 5. That means we can do just like this.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
   if(array_key_exist($key, range(0,5))
      continue;
   echo $value."<br/>"
}
```

or we can using `for...` loop

```
for($ind = 0; $ind < count($array); $ind++){    
    if(array_key_exist($ind, range(0,5))
      continue;    
echo $arr[$ind]."<br/>" 
}
```

How could i skip the index without using continue or searching the array_key first ? sure the code above looks fine to me, but if i have a bunch of arrays keys and values, i think this is not a good choice.

Comment: Why not just start your `for` loop at 6? `for($ind = 6; $ind < count($array); $ind++){` then you don't need a check in the loop at all.

Comment: @Nick well that's correct, but i need to do this way, rather than start the loop at 6, beacuse this is just a basic case for bigger case, so i need to know the basic how to skipped loop for certain range of index.

Comment: Using `array_key_exists` would be pretty inefficient. It would be faster to just use `if ($ind >= 0 && $ind <= 5) continue;`. But... without seeing the true complexity of what you are trying to do (you mention "a bunch of arrays keys and values") it's hard to offer a good solution.

Comment: How about using `array_diff` and then loop on that output?

Comment: If you want to skip arbitrary range of keys {not necessary from the beginning or end of array}, best choice would be to use `print_r(array_diff_key($array, array_flip(range(3,5))));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the slice of array from 5th index to rest,

```
$result = array_slice($array,5,count($array)-5, true);
```

[array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) — Extract a slice of the array

> **Note**:
>
> array_slice() will reorder and reset the integer array indices by
>   default. This behaviour can be changed by setting preserve_keys to
>   TRUE. String keys are always preserved, regardless of this parameter.

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/975c27787958bbacc1413a3f55757451807d52f6).

Comment: is there a way to make the index number not re-ordered from 0 again ?

Comment: Pardon mate. But I didn't understand, what you just say

Comment: sorry, i mean, your answer make the value `number 6` and the rest have the index key re-ordered from the index `0`. Is it possible to kept the old index key ?, so the value `number 6` still have `5` for its key.

Comment: Yes its possible, pass true as last parameter. Check my updated answer

Comment: Your welcome mate! FYI, I updated my answer with a note of array_slice behaviour for better understanding. Thanks for the EDIT.

Comment: @Gagantous you should be able to pass `null` for the third parameter and omit the additional call to `count()`. If the length parameter is null it will just include the rest of the array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) as:

```
$wantKeys = array_diff(array_keys($array), range(1,5));
```

Now all you need is loop on the `$wantKeys` as:

```
foreach($wantKeys as $k) 
    echo $array[$k]; // only wanted values
```

The same idea can be achieve by [array_diff_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php):

```
$wantKeys = array_diff_key($array, array_flip(range(1,5)));
```

Comment: oh this is nice! but i will wait for another answer, thanks for the answer!